# Is this Fibonacci function right?

Tags: php, fibonacci-sequence

Is this a correct method of Fibonacci with recursion?

```
function fibb($limit,$first_numer=0,$second_number=1){
        echo $first_numer."\n";
        echo $second_number."\n";
        if($limit > 0){
            fibb($limit-2,$first_numer+$second_number,($first_numer+$second_number+$second_number));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In a sense, your function does produce the right numbers.  However, the termination condition is not quite right.  For example, `fibb(3)` and `fibb(4)` produce identical output: each prints six numbers.  Why six?  The most natural interpretation of the parameters would be that `$limit` should specify the number of items in the sequence to be printed.

The root of the problem is that each call to `fibb()` prints two lines, which means that output will always be printed in pairs.  Normally, you would want to print just one number per call.

In addition, your naming is unconventional.  Why `fibb()` with two `b`s?  Also, `$first_numer` is misspelled.

```
function fibonacci($limit, $first_number=0, $second_number=1) {
    if ($limit <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    echo "$first_number\n";
    fibonacci($limit - 1, $second_number, $first_number + $second_number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that programmers can write code with their own logic. You should get the correct output (with less code, which is great).

There are many ways to do the same, such as:

```
<?php
function fibonacci ($n)
{
   if ($n == 0) {
      return 0;
   }
   else if ($n == 1)
   {
      return 1;
   } else {
      return fibonacci( $n - 1 ) + fibonacci( $n - 2 );
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to CodeReview. [Code-only](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/short-answers-and-code-only-answers) answers are not the best format for a code review. How is your code different? Why is it better? See [how to answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and add these details to your answer and you will have a much higher quality result